# How to join two armatures with separate meshes?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

So I created two different rigs, one for my body and one for my eyes.

When I try to join the eye rig to the body rig, my eyes get moved and I tried setting the origin but each option results in the same outcome.

Here's my eye rig. Pink bone control eye movements and yellow controls eyelids

[image]

Here's my body rig

[image]

Now when I click on the eye rig then the body and press cltr + j, the eyes get pushed down like this

[image]

When I joined the meshes then parent the eyes, the eyelids still don't move

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/767a38c088db4fe684011dfcd0ee78fd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the scale of the armature *Body Rig*:

[image]

Comment: my only issue is now the eye lids don't move with the body and if I try to parent them to the eye rig, when I move my body rig the eye lids don't move. Im referring to in pose mode btw when I move the body rig, the eyelids don't move or the eye rig

Comment: you need to correctly parent the bones to each other and parent the lid and eyes to the good bones

Comment: I parented the eyes to the armature bone and it works fine, but for some reason when I do the same thing to the eyelids it doesn't move. Where do I parent the eyelids to? I only have the armature option or my eyes, but so far "bone" doesn't work

Comment: also after I joined the two armatures, when I move the body rig, the eye armature doesn't even move which makes no sense since they're joined together?

Comment: it really depends on how you plan to parent the mesh to the armature, do you want your meshes to be separate objects or to be all parts of the same object, etc?

Comment: the eye bones don't move because they are not parented to any bone in your armature, parent them to Ctrl_Spine

Comment: I want both rigs to be combined into one so I can edit eye movement and body movement together. Also, how can I parent the eye bones if I already combined them together?

Comment: in Edit mode, select Eye.l, shift select Ctrl_Spine, then Ctrl P > (Make Parent) Keep Offset

Comment: the problem is my eyelid contains a driver with a constraint, so no matter where I move my rig, that constraint keeps it still

Comment: the discussion is getting too complicated for BlenderStackExchange  ^^  maybe you should watch some tutorials on how people rig heads etc (there are several solutions of course, it's a bit complicated to understand what you're trying to achieve through BSE)

Comment: I added one last pic at the bottom of my question. Everything looks fine except the eyelids which is my only thing not moving with the rest of my rig

Comment: How do you want to parent the eyes and eyelids to the bones? What you can do is unparent the eyes, remove their Armature modifier, put their origin to geometry, remove the drivers of the eyelids, put origin to geometry as well, select one eye, shift select the armature, switch to pose mode, select the bone to which you need parent and Ctrl P (Parent) > Bone, same thing for the other eye and for the eyelids. Another way would be to join all the meshes together and parent With Empty Groups and assign the right vertex group to the eyes and eyelids

Comment: I made a new question showing my new issue, I got the general parent almost right yet it still has some issues when moving in pose mode. I'll accept ur current answer here since i fixed the basic issue